# Cabal - mismatched interface file versions (wanted "7063", got "7042")

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have upgraded to ghc-7.6.3 and now I am having difficulty with cabal install which fails right near the end. The module compiles with ghc and runs OK.

The error is:

cabal: Bad interface file: dist/build/Sync.hi
mismatched interface file versions (wanted "7063", got "7042")

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks

N

UPDATE:

Thanks for the suggestions - the error was actually simpler. For some reason I had commented out the module declaration at the top of the file - so the build/dist directory only had files called Main not Sync. I wonder if the error messages might be able to suggest this?

---

Here is the output from cabal install -v:

```
Reading available packages...
Choosing modular solver.
Resolving dependencies...
Ready to install Sync-0.0
Waiting for install task to finish...
Configuring Sync-0.0...
Dependency Date ==0.0: using Date-0.0
Dependency MissingH ==1.2.0.2: using MissingH-1.2.0.2
Dependency base ==4.6.0.1: using base-4.6.0.1
Dependency directory ==1.2.0.1: using directory-1.2.0.1
Dependency filepath ==1.3.0.1: using filepath-1.3.0.1
Dependency ftphs ==1.0.9.1: using ftphs-1.0.9.1
Dependency time ==1.4.0.1: using time-1.4.0.1
Using Cabal-1.16.0 compiled by ghc-7.6
Using compiler: ghc-7.6.3
Using install prefix: /home/nick/.cabal
Binaries installed in: /home/nick/.cabal/bin
Libraries installed in: /home/nick/.cabal/lib/Sync-0.0/ghc-7.6.3
Private binaries installed in: /home/nick/.cabal/libexec
Data files installed in: /home/nick/.cabal/share/Sync-0.0
Documentation installed in: /home/nick/.cabal/share/doc/Sync-0.0
Using alex version 3.0.5 found on system at: /usr/local/bin/alex
Using ar found on system at: /usr/bin/ar
No c2hs found
No cpphs found
No ffihugs found
Using gcc version 4.7 found on system at: /usr/bin/gcc
Using ghc version 7.6.3 found on system at: /usr/local/bin/ghc
Using ghc-pkg version 7.6.3 found on system at: /usr/local/bin/ghc-pkg
No greencard found
Using haddock version 2.13.2 found on system at: /usr/local/bin/haddock
Using happy version 1.18.10 found on system at: /usr/local/bin/happy
No hmake found
Using hpc version 0.6 found on system at: /usr/local/bin/hpc
Using hsc2hs version 0.67 found on system at: /usr/local/bin/hsc2hs
No hscolour found
No hugs found
No jhc found
Using ld found on system at: /usr/bin/ld
No lhc found
No lhc-pkg found
No nhc98 found
Using pkg-config version 0.26 found on system at: /usr/bin/pkg-config
Using ranlib found on system at: /usr/bin/ranlib
Using strip found on system at: /usr/bin/strip
Using tar found on system at: /bin/tar
No uhc found
creating dist/build
creating dist/build/autogen
Building Sync-0.0...
Preprocessing library Sync-0.0...
Building library...
creating dist/build
/usr/local/bin/ghc --make -fbuilding-cabal-package -O -odir dist/build -hidir dist/build -stubdir dist/build -i -idist/build -i. -idist/build/autogen -Idist/build/autogen -Idist/build -optP-include -optPdist/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h -package-name Sync-0.0 -hide-all-packages -package-db dist/package.conf.inplace -package-id Date-0.0-3350631060e088b8c47dc7662550baf5 -package-id MissingH-1.2.0.2-a99e1d5ebd0f0e16c2a6d3a888b9fc5e -package-id base-4.6.0.1-ced5f3d8c90960e9f372129163296e44 -package-id directory-1.2.0.1-0f6696fb1143d7612e79f8dad6bc63a4 -package-id filepath-1.3.0.1-edbc3d8247914b04f448e9261e7fe895 -package-id ftphs-1.0.9.1-800800add85e83623dc006b8fcce2c73 -package-id time-1.4.0.1-11ddabfbdd9e1882a9135b100d37881b -XHaskell98 Sync -Wall
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Sync.hs, dist/build/Main.o )

Sync.hs:57:27: Warning: Defined but not used: `fusr'

Sync.hs:58:27: Warning: Defined but not used: `fpwd'

Sync.hs:60:27: Warning: Defined but not used: `fres'

Sync.hs:64:31: Warning: Defined but not used: `fsize'

Sync.hs:91:1: Warning: Defined but not used: `die'

Sync.hs:116:13: Warning:
    This binding for `pwd' shadows the existing binding
      imported from `Network.FTP.Client' at Sync.hs:36:1-25

Sync.hs:214:1: Warning: Defined but not used: `dontCopyFile'

Sync.hs:53:10: Warning:
    Orphan instance: instance Show FTPConnection
Linking...
/usr/bin/ar -r dist/build/libHSSync-0.0.a dist/build/Sync.o
/usr/bin/ar: creating dist/build/libHSSync-0.0.a
/usr/bin/ld -x --hash-size=31 --reduce-memory-overheads -r -o dist/build/HSSync-0.0.o dist/build/Sync.o
In-place registering Sync-0.0...
/usr/local/bin/ghc-pkg update - --global --user --package-db=dist/package.conf.inplace
directory dist/doc/html/Sync does exist: False
creating /home/nick/.cabal/share/doc/Sync-0.0
Installing LICENSE to /home/nick/.cabal/share/doc/Sync-0.0/LICENSE
Installing library in /home/nick/.cabal/lib/Sync-0.0/ghc-7.6.3
creating /home/nick/.cabal/lib/Sync-0.0/ghc-7.6.3
Installing dist/build/Sync.hi to
/home/nick/.cabal/lib/Sync-0.0/ghc-7.6.3/Sync.hi
creating /home/nick/.cabal/lib/Sync-0.0/ghc-7.6.3
Installing dist/build/libHSSync-0.0.a to
/home/nick/.cabal/lib/Sync-0.0/ghc-7.6.3/libHSSync-0.0.a
creating /home/nick/.cabal/lib/Sync-0.0/ghc-7.6.3
Installing dist/build/HSSync-0.0.o to
/home/nick/.cabal/lib/Sync-0.0/ghc-7.6.3/HSSync-0.0.o
/usr/local/bin/ghc --abi-hash -fbuilding-cabal-package -O -odir dist/build -hidir dist/build -stubdir dist/build -i -idist/build -i. -idist/build/autogen -Idist/build/autogen -Idist/build -optP-include -optPdist/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h -package-name Sync-0.0 -hide-all-packages -package-id Date-0.0-3350631060e088b8c47dc7662550baf5 -package-id MissingH-1.2.0.2-a99e1d5ebd0f0e16c2a6d3a888b9fc5e -package-id base-4.6.0.1-ced5f3d8c90960e9f372129163296e44 -package-id directory-1.2.0.1-0f6696fb1143d7612e79f8dad6bc63a4 -package-id filepath-1.3.0.1-edbc3d8247914b04f448e9261e7fe895 -package-id ftphs-1.0.9.1-800800add85e83623dc006b8fcce2c73 -package-id time-1.4.0.1-11ddabfbdd9e1882a9135b100d37881b -XHaskell98 Sync -Wall
cabal: Bad interface file: dist/build/Sync.hi
mismatched interface file versions (wanted "7063", got "7042")
Failed to install Sync-0.0
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
Sync-0.0 failed during the final install step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Comment: I think you can try deleting your `~/.cabal` and running `cabal install ...` in a "fresh" environment.

Comment: `cabal clean` should be enough.